# Редирект с исключением

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект

Необходимо сделать постоянный редирект для всех, за исключением поисковых ботов, возможно ли такое? Спасибо огромное за Вашу помощь.
`Redirect 301 /test-1/ http://site.ru/test-2/`

Answer (score -1):

ВЫ можете создать файл индексации robots.txt и вписать туда

```
google-bot
yandex-bot
yahoo-bot
```

Comment: Это влияет на индексацию, но не имеет отношения к переадресации.